# Does the system processor/ configuration plays role in program execution?

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

I implemented dijkstra's algorithm in python.
I run the same program in 4 different system, but the result was surprising.

An intel xeon processor, 64 gb ram desktop took exactly same time (1.21 sec) as taken by a pentium dual core 1 gb ram desktop.

How is it possible?
Please tell me whether program execution depend on following factors:

1. System Processor
2. OS
3. RAM
4. Programing language.
5. System cache memory.

Who's effect is maximum.

Answer (score 0):

All factors plus a lot more (say the motherboard, disks) play a role.

In your case however you use python. Python usually uses only one CPU core so having less/more cores plays no role. The size of the memory would play any role if you need a lot of RAM, you most likely did not need much.

For simple python scripts I think only CPU speed (family...) and memory (RAM) speed play any role.

The question is what resources your program uses. In your case disk speed, memory size, network card, OS and so on most likely do not play any role.

Comment: Thanks , could you please give me some links from where I can read more in detail and I have to give references as well.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock is good to know (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html for overcoming it) and maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_performance would be a good start...